# Elemento sobrepuesto a un Framelayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Coloqué un `FrameLayout` azul (ver imagen) y lo muevo con el dedo, pero se oculta cuando paso por el borde del `FrameLayout` padre, y la idea es que siempre este sobrepuesto, pero que siga añadido en el `Framelayout` padre

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código actual:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/moverFrme"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"></FrameLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Clase mueve con el dedo el Framelayout hijo

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {

 FrameLayout move;
        float dX, dY;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            move = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.moverFrme);
            move.setOnTouchListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
        {
            if (v == move && e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                dX = v.getX() - e.getRawX();
                dY = v.getY() - e.getRawY();
            }

            if (v == move && e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
            {
                move.setY(e.getRawY()+dY);
                move.setX(e.getRawX()+dX);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es que el cuadro grande sea el padre de los dos framelayouts, de esa manera ambos serían hijos y podrían moverse con libertad solo que con disitintos tamaños.

Comment: Claro porqué tu `FrameLayout` está dentro de otro entonces no va a mostrar más allá de donde se ha declarado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución es agregar al `Framelayout` llamado `activity_main` la siguiente opción:

```
android:clipChildren="false"
```

---

Esta es la definición de la propiedad:

> [android:clipChildren](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android:clipChildren) Define si una vista hija está limitada a dibujar
>   dentro de sus límites o no.

Comment: El problema ahora es que si dejo el FrameLayout `moverFrme` afuera de su padre, ya no me deja moverlo.

Comment: No sabia de esta propiedad, edité un poco tu respuesta, gracias por el aporte, saludos. @AlbertBarrientos

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es que el cuadro grande sea el padre de los dos *framelayouts*, de esa manera ambos serían hijos solo que con distintos tamaños y podrían moverse con libertad .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    >
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        ></FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/moverFrme"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
            android:padding="12dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"></FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```