# Mover elemento hijo

Tags: android, android-layout

A causa de [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/47029/elemento-sobrepuesto-a-un-framelayout) ahora puedo mover un hijo del `Framelayout` afuera de los límites de su padre, pero el problema es que si suelto el `Framelayout` hijo afuera de los límites de su padre, ya no puedo moverlo, aquí lo que sucede:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código de `activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/parentMove"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/move2"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            android:elevation="10dp">
        </FrameLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Código de `MainActivity`:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener
{

    FrameLayout move2, parentMove, activity_main;
    float dX2, dY2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        activity_main = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        activity_main.setOnTouchListener(this);

        parentMove = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentMove);
        parentMove.setOnTouchListener(this);

        move2 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.move2);
        move2.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
    {
        if (v == move2)
        {
            Log.d("PINCHO","move2");
        }

        if ( v == activity_main)
        {
            Log.d("PINCHO","activity_main");
        }

        if ( v == parentMove)
        {
            Log.d("PINCHO","parentMove");
        }

        if (v == move2 && e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            dX2 = v.getX() - e.getRawX();
            dY2 = v.getY() - e.getRawY();
        }

        if (v == move2 && e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
        {
            move2.setY(e.getRawY()+dY2);
            move2.setX(e.getRawX()+dX2);
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Una solución es que cuando suelte el `Framelayout` hijo le cambio el padre y dejo que su padre sea el layout en el cual se suelta, pero debo hacer una conversión de eje de coordenadas y funcionaria bien

Comment: O es que lo deje como hijo del `Framelayout` padre y haga una conversión de eje de coordenadas

Answer (score -1):

No es viable hacer que el padre cubra la totalidad de la pantalla? Armas un FrameLayout principal, uno que contenga el objeto que se mueve, y otro que contenga toda la pantalla.

```
<FrameLayout>

   <RelativeLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>

   <CustomView>
   </CustomView>

</FrameLayout>
```